# Gmail as icon on Dock in os x

Tags: gmail, google-chrome, mac

On Windows, I can add Gmail as a faux application to the Taskbar, by using something like "add to task bar" in the Wrench->Tools menu. This promotes it to appear as a native application in the task bar.

I notice that the same menu item isn't there for Chrome on Mac - at least, not in the same place. I'm looking for a "Add to Dock" function.

Can this be done on the OS X version of Chrome? If so, how? I'm sick of having my email client hanging out with the other browser tabs.

Comment: Try [Fluid](http://fluidapp.com/).

Comment: @Alex Fluid uses Apple's WebKit, and not Google Chrome.

Comment: @ThomasPloeger so does Chrome ([Google Chrome is a freeware web browser developed by Google that _uses the WebKit layout engine_.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome)). Besides, that’s not important; the OP wants to use Gmail as a desktop app and that’s exactly what Fluid does.

Comment: The question was if this could be done with (the OS X Version of) Chrome. But you're right, it is the same engine so the differences will be negligible - unless you also want to have some Chrome specific functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Fluid](http://fluidapp.com/).

> Fluid lets you create a Real Mac App (*or “Fluid App”*) out of any website or web application, effectively turning your favorite web apps into OS X desktop apps.